# MLP Neural Network: calculating the gradient (matrices)

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, gradient

## What is a good implementation for calculating the gradient in a n-layered neural network?

**Weight layers:**

1. First layer weights:     `(n_inputs+1, n_units_layer)-matrix`
2. Hidden layer weights: `(n_units_layer+1, n_units_layer)-matrix`
3. Last layer weights:     `(n_units_layer+1, n_outputs)-matrix`

Notes:

- If there is only one hidden layer we would represent the net by using just two (weight) layers:
  `inputs --first_layer-> network_unit --second_layer-> output`
- For a n-layer network with more than one hidden layer, we need to implement the (2) step.

---

#### A bit vague pseudocode:

```
    weight_layers = [ layer1, layer2 ]             # a list of layers as described above
    input_values  = [ [0,0], [0,0], [1,0], [0,1] ] # our test set (corresponds to XOR)
    target_output = [ 0, 0, 1, 1 ]                 # what we want to train our net to output
    output_layers = []                             # output for the corresponding layers

    for layer in weight_layers:
        output <-- calculate the output     # calculate the output from the current layer
        output_layers <-- output            # store the output from each layer
    
    n_samples = input_values.shape[0]
    n_outputs = target_output.shape[1]
    
    error = ( output-target_output )/( n_samples*n_outputs )

    """ calculate the gradient here """
```

---

## Final implementation

[The final implementation is available at github](https://github.com/jorgenkg/python-neural-network).

Comment: Hi, just curious. Can this code work for multivariate outputs?(i.e. output layer has more than 1 neuron)

Comment: Yes, just specify the number of outputs during the initialization of the network object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Python and numpy that is easy.

You have two options:

1. You can either compute everything in parallel for `num_instances` instances or
2. you can compute the gradient for one instance (which is actually a special case of 1.).

I will now give some hints how to implement option 1. I would suggest that you create a new class that is called `Layer`. It should have two functions:

```
forward:
    inputs:
    X: shape = [num_instances, num_inputs]
        inputs
    W: shape = [num_outputs, num_inputs]
        weights
    b: shape = [num_outputs]
        biases
    g: function
        activation function
    outputs:
    Y: shape = [num_instances, num_outputs]
        outputs


backprop:
    inputs:
    dE/dY: shape = [num_instances, num_outputs]
        backpropagated gradient
    W: shape = [num_outputs, num_inputs]
        weights
    b: shape = [num_outputs]
        biases
    gd: function
        calculates the derivative of g(A) = Y
        based on Y, i.e. gd(Y) = g'(A)
    Y: shape = [num_instances, num_outputs]
        outputs
    X: shape = [num_instances, num_inputs]
        inputs
    outputs:
    dE/dX: shape = [num_instances, num_inputs]
        will be backpropagated (dE/dY of lower layer)
    dE/dW: shape = [num_outputs, num_inputs]
        accumulated derivative with respect to weights
    dE/db: shape = [num_outputs]
        accumulated derivative with respect to biases
```

The implementation is simple:

```
def forward(X, W, b):
    A = X.dot(W.T) + b # will be broadcasted
    Y = g(A)
    return Y

def backprop(dEdY, W, b, gd, Y, X):
    Deltas = gd(Y) * dEdY # element-wise multiplication
    dEdX = Deltas.dot(W)
    dEdW = Deltas.T.dot(X)
    dEdb = Deltas.sum(axis=0)
    return dEdX, dEdW, dEdb
```

`X` of the first layer is your taken from your dataset and then you pass each `Y` as the `X` of the next layer in the forward pass.

The `dE/dY` of the output layer is computed (either for softmax activation function and cross entropy error function or for linear activation function and sum of squared errors) as `Y-T`, where `Y` is the output of the network (shape = [num_instances, num_outputs]) and `T` (shape = [num_instances, num_outputs]) is the desired output. Then you can backpropagate, i.e. `dE/dX` of each layer is `dE/dY` of the previous layer.

Now you can use `dE/dW` and `dE/db` of each layer to update `W` and `b`.

Here is an example for C++: [OpenANN](https://github.com/OpenANN/OpenANN/blob/master/src/FullyConnected.cpp).

Btw. you can compare the speed of instance-wise and batch-wise forward propagation:

```
In [1]: import timeit

In [2]: setup = """import numpy
   ...: W = numpy.random.rand(10, 5000)
   ...: X = numpy.random.rand(1000, 5000)"""

In [3]: timeit.timeit('[W.dot(x) for x in X]', setup=setup, number=10)
Out[3]: 0.5420958995819092

In [4]: timeit.timeit('X.dot(W.T)', setup=setup, number=10)
Out[4]: 0.22001314163208008
```

Comment: Super handy formatting! I would have kept voting you up!
_A heads-up for reader_: for the conjugate gradient method, only the `dE/dX` method is required in the `backprop()` method

Comment: Thanks. :) But usually nonlinear conjugate gradient also requires (dEdW, dEdb) to update (W, b) so that E will be minimized. dEdX is only required for backpropagation.

Comment: The implemented code snippet is a scaled conjugate gradient algorithm that uses the Polak-Ribiere formula for updating the search direction. Which would add up to being a nonlinear cg algorithm, though I might be mistaken! Either way: the only calculation necessary in the `backpropagation()` is `np.dot( error, weights )*dAdY(output_values)` where `def A() # activation function`

Comment: How exactly do you update the weights then? Of course it is also possible to adjust the inputs of the neural network (the dataset) so that it minimizes the error function. :D

Comment: I don't directly adjust the weight, but adjust the  `Δw_i` such that `perfect_weight_i = initial_weight_i + Δw_i`

Comment: And how do you generate Δw_i?

Comment: `Δw_i = α * d` where `α # step size` and `d # search direction`
`d = -initial_gradient # updated by Polak-Ribiere`
`≈Hessian = np.dot(d, gradient(x + μ*d) - gradient(x))/μ # for some small μ`
`α = ( d.dot(current_gradient) )/( ≈Hessian + scaling_factor*np.dot(d, d) ) # where scaling_factor is updated within the algorithm`

I am sorry for not making this clearer, but calculus is not meant for the discussion field on **SO**.

Comment: ...and what are gradient(x) and initial_gradient in this case? I guess gradient(x) is actually (dEdW, dEdb) for each layer organized in a flat vector.

Comment: That is correct. The `backprop()` method is propagating the error throughout the layers and for each layer we calculate the 
`np.dot( dEdX_previous_layer,output_from_layer`. Such that the only necessary function is `def backprop():dEdX`. The matrix arithmetics in the Scaled Conjugate Gradient algorithm will take care of adjusting the weights for each dimension in `dimension(weight_vector)`

Comment: I didn't fully understand that implementation but I think it is definitely not the standard conjugate gradient which usually takes the derivative of an objective function with respect to some parameter x to update the parameter x (where x could also be W or b). Polak-Ribiere (like Fletcher-Reeves) is usually just a type of preconditioner.